# Implementing getarg subroutine call

Tags: fortran, command-line-arguments, filenames

I've written a program in F90 which reads in a few input arrays from text files and then combines them through a function to a single output file. One of the input files is named for the day the data was collected using MMDDYY.tuvr and the output file is then named MMDDYY.fxi . I'd like to be able to input the MMDDYY of the data in the command line when running the program instead of having to manually change the code and compile each time, which is why I'm attempting to use getarg, but I cannot seem to make it work properly. The code im attempting to use is listed below (just shows the get arg and the open commands and not the entire program since this is where I'm having trouble):

```
CHARACTER(len=20) :: arg, tuvrname, fxiname
CALL getarg(1, arg)
IF(LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) THEN
    print*,'No date provided'
    STOP
ELSE
    tuvrname = TRIM(arg)'.tuvr'
    fxiname = TRIM(arg).'fxi'
ENDIF

OPEN(1, file = tuvrname, status='old', action='read')
....
OPEN(4, file = fxiname, status='replace', action='write')
```

I also tried just using two separate getarg commands and entering MMDDDYY.tuvr MMDDYY.fxi in the command line and the program ran, but it could not seem to find my TUVR file as the output was empty.

Comment: If I were really nit-picking, I would say you did not write a program in F90, but in a proprietary extension language to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really experienced in using `getarg`. I use `get_command_argument` from Fortran 2003. I think you just forgot to use `//` to concatenate the strings.

```
CHARACTER(len=20) :: arg, tuvrname, fxiname
CALL getarg(1, arg)
IF(LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) THEN
    print*,'No date provided'
    STOP
ELSE
    tuvrname = TRIM(arg)//'.tuvr'
    fxiname = TRIM(arg)//'.fxi'
ENDIF

print *, tuvrname, fxiname

end
```

or

```
CHARACTER(len=20) :: arg, tuvrname, fxiname
if (command_argument_count()<1) then
  stop "Provide the file name."
end if
CALL get_command_argument(1, value=arg)

tuvrname = TRIM(arg)//'.tuvr'
fxiname = TRIM(arg)//'.fxi'

print *, tuvrname, fxiname

end
```

Comment: I  implemented the following:
    `CHARACTER(len=20) :: arg, tuvrname, fxiname
    CALL getarg(1, arg)
    IF(LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) THEN
        print*,'No date provided'
        STOP
    ELSE
        tuvrname = TRIM(arg)//'.tuvr'
        fxiname = TRIM(arg)//'.fxi'
    ENDIF`

But after compiling I enter './createfxi AP2412' in the command prompt and it gives me the 'No date provided' output. Not sure what is going on

Comment: Also, see your compiler manual for exact definition of your getarg, it can behave slightly differently than mine, it is nonstandard.