# Getting error unresolved external symbol _GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT@12 , GETARG@12 in Fortran powerstation

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I tried to use the get_command_argument property of Fortran. But while running build function, the following errors are displayed by Microsoft developer studio. I am new to Fortran, I have used the examples from the links below. Please help me.
Thanks

```
Example 1. 
PROGRAM test_get_command_argument
INTEGER :: i
CHARACTER(len=32) :: arg
i = 0
DO
CALL get_command_argument(i, arg)
IF (LEN_TRIM(arg) == 0) EXIT
WRITE (*,*) TRIM(arg)
i = i+1
END DO
END PROGRAM

--------------------Configuration: Text1 - Win32 Debug--------------------
Linking...
Text1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT@12
Text1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
Text1.exe - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)




Example 2. 
PROGRAM cmdlnsum
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER(100) :: num1char
CHARACTER(100) :: num2char
REAL :: num1
REAL :: num2
REAL :: numsum

!First, make sure the right number of inputs have been provided
IF(COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT().NE.2)THEN
  WRITE(*,*)'ERROR, TWO COMMAND-LINE ARGUMENTS REQUIRED, STOPPING'
  STOP
ENDIF

CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(1,num1char)   !first, read in the two values
CALL GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT(2,num2char)

READ(num1char,*)num1                    !then, convert them to REALs
READ(num2char,*)num2

numsum=num1+num2                        !sum numbers
WRITE(*,*)numsum                        !write out value

END PROGRAM

Linking...
fortran_program.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT@12
fortran_program.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT@0
fortran_program.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
fortran_program.exe - 3 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

[Implementing getarg subroutine call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369096/implementing-getarg-subroutine-call/15369655#15369655?newreg=eb711ae07aab43e3b7927ab7cfd6499c)
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GET_005fCOMMAND_005fARGUMENT.html
https://riptutorial.com/fortran/example/26615/passing-command-line-arguments

Comment: What compiler and version of it are you using? Do you expect it to support this part of Fortran 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title and reference to "Developer Studio", I suspect you are trying to use Microsoft Powerstation Fortran.  If so, that compiler, last released in the mid 1990's, does not support the GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT or COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT intrinsic procedures.  These intrinsic procedures are specified in the 2003 revision of the Fortran standard.